# Tooltip with HTML in R Shiny with BS5 theme?

Tags: r, shiny, bootstrap-5

The following code produces a tooltip which becomes visible on click and formats the HTML content correctly:

```
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  # theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "pulse"),
  
  tags$head(tags$script(
    "
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('[data-toggle=\"tooltip\"]').tooltip({
        trigger: 'click'
      });
    });
  ")),
  
  selectInput(
    inputId = "action",
    label   = tags$span(tags$i(`data-toggle` = "tooltip",
                               `data-placement` = "right",
                               `data-html` = TRUE,
                               title = "This is:<br>My <b>tooltip</b> text!",
                               icon("circle-info")),
                        "More label text."),
    choices = c(1,2,3),
    selected = 1
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

However, when I activate the call to `bs_theme` the HTML in the tooltip stops to work.

I suspect this has to do with BS5 sanitization. I have checked in the [BS5 tooltip documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/tooltips/) but I'm uncertain exactly how to translate these options to Shiny and haven't managed getting it to work. Any suggestions for how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```r
library(shiny)
library(bslib)

ui <- fluidPage(
  
  theme = bs_theme(version = 5, bootswatch = "pulse"),
  
  tags$head(tags$script(
    "
    $(document).ready(function(){
      var tooltipTriggerList = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('[data-bs-toggle=\"tooltip\"]'));
      var tooltipList = tooltipTriggerList.map(function (tooltipTriggerEl) {
        return new bootstrap.Tooltip(tooltipTriggerEl);
      });
    });
  ")),
  
  selectInput(
    inputId = "action",
    label   = tags$span(tags$i(`data-bs-toggle` = "tooltip",
                               `data-bs-placement` = "right",
                               `data-bs-html` = "true",
                               title = "This is:<br>My <b>tooltip</b> text!",
                               icon("circle-info")),
                        "More label text."),
    choices = c(1,2,3),
    selected = 1
  )
  
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks! So I had to write `data-bs-html` = "true" with quotation marks, that solved a lot, thanks!  :)